# How to hide scrollbars in WebView in Windows 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, scrollbar

I am trying to hide scrollbars in my metro application like i usually do in windows phone app:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" 
    Height="395" Width="300"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

But it does not work even if i surround it with embedded

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewerForWebView"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

    <WebView x:Name="webView" Height="395" Width="300" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what if you set

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```